# Changes on selected node reflected on the main document - htmlagilitypack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack, local-variables, selectsinglenode

I am selecting a node with for example

```
HtmlDocument temp_HdDocument = new HtmlDocument();

temp_HdDocument.LoadHtml(mysource);

var vrTempNewNode = temp_HdDocument.SelectSingleNode("//a"));
```

I change node this way

```
foreach (HtmlNode node in vrTempNewNode.SelectNodes("*"))
{
    node.Remove();
}
```

Now when i make any changes on `vrTempNewNode` it is also reflected at `temp_HdDocument`

How can i prevent this happening ? I suppose select node just creates a reference object but i want it to be a new local variable not a part of main document

htmlagilitypack c# .net 4.5 wpf

Comment: Could you update your question with how you're changing it as well...

Comment: "I suppose select node just creates a reference object..."   Exactly right, you'll need to clone/copy the nodes to get independent entities.

Comment: @Prix i added how i modify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the default behavior, and it's very handy in most case. You can use `HtmlNode.CopyFrom()` to create an independent copy of the existing node that you can then modify without affecting the original `HtmlDocument`, for example :

```
var a = temp_HdDocument.SelectSingleNode("//a"));
HtmlNode temp = HtmlNode.CreateNode("<a></a>");
temp.CopyFrom(a, false);
```

Comment: ok it works with way i suppose :   vrTempNewNode.CopyFrom(vrTempNewNode2, false);

Comment: you're right, I tried that just now. That's seems a bug : [HtmlNode.CopyFrom deep parameter works the opposite](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/workitem/26247)